# How to compute $\int_0^t s d B_s$ and $\int_0^t B_s ds$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Consider the Itō integral $X_t := \int_0^t s \,dB_s$.

Here is my attempt. Let $f(t,x) = tx$. By Itō's formula,
$$ d f(t, B_t) = B_t dt + t dB_t $$
so
$$ t B_t = \int_0^t B_s\, ds + \int_0^t s \,dB_s. $$
But how is $\int_0^t B_s\,ds$ calculated?

Are $\int_0^t f(s) \,dB_s$ and $\int_0^t f(s, B_s)\,ds$  not solvable for any $f$, and generally left as they are when computing Itō integrals and solving Itō SDEs?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: That bar over the 'o' in [Itō Kiyoshi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiyoshi_It%C5%8D)'s name is called a [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron) and is used in [romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romaji) of Japanese.

Comment: @kahen: I don't know how to write macrons, so please forgive me...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an explicit formula for $\int_0^t B_s ds$ but as it is a limit of normal random variables it is still a normal random variable and thus you just need to calculate its variance and mean. It is not difficult to see that $E\left( \int_0^t B_s ds \right)$ is zero. The variance is a little more tricky we have

\begin{align}E\left( \left( \int_0^t B_s ds \right)^2 \right) &= E\left( \int_0^t \int_0^t B_u B_s \, du \, ds \right) \\ \, &= \int_0^t \int_0^t E(B_u B_s) \, du \, ds \\ \, &= \int_0^t \int_0^t \min(u, s) \, du \, ds = \frac{t^3}{3}
\end{align}
The Fubini steps can be all well justified.

Comment: Thanks! When solving ito integrals and Ito SDEs, are we satisfied and stop when the results contain only $\int f(B_s) ds$ and/or $\int f(s) dB_s$, without continuing  to solve $\int f(B_s) ds$ and/or $\int f(s) dB_s$?

Comment: I think so. I mean, you could use Ito's formula to find alternative presentations of these integrals, but if you already used it once you are most likely going back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The Fubini trick is nice. But consider finding distribution of $\int_0^t B_s ds$ using integration by parts and Ito isometry:
$$X_t=\int_0^t B_s ds=tB_t-\int_0^tsdB_s=\int_0^t(t-s)dB_s$$
So as $t-s$ is deterministic, this thing is a mean 0 Gaussian process with independent increments with covariance function
$$Cov(X_s,X_t)=\int_0^{\min(s,t)} (t-u)(s-u)du$$